# Eclipse crashes with a GC overhead limit exceeded error

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, proguard, overhead

It's the first time I am using Proguard, I've noticed that if you add many custom rules to `proguard-project.txt` it takes obviously much more time for building. That's cause Eclipse to crash reporting a `GC overhead limit exceeded` and then I have to force the shut down of java because the editor continues to pop out error and alert dialogs. Is there any way to avoid these continuous crashes on Eclipse and so fix the problem reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) too?

Comment: Fixed, I read all the others forum posts about the problem but no one said how to fix it on Eclipse. I found the fix here http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: A good idea is to post the solution as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. That will make it easy for others who might find this through google.

Comment: Ok but I have to wait for the answer because I have less than 10 reputation. I hope to not forget...

Comment: @Fredrik I answered to my question and marked it as an accepted solution after many hours of waiting due to my new subscription. I edited the question too as adviced by stackoverflow and because of it is marked as duplicate. I hope I have fixed it, because, as I previously wrote you in a comment, I already read that post but even if the error is well explained no one say how to fix it in Eclipse, so I thought to open a new question and not answer that one related only to the error. I hope I have not compromised my reputation on StackOverflow now that I have just joined it. Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question because the question that it is supposedly a duplicate of is about how to fix this error when you get it in your own code, but this question is about how to fix it in a program that someone else wrote and you are using (i.e. Eclipse) which is different.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Fixed, I read all the others forum posts about the problem but no one said how to fix it on Eclipse. I found the fix [here](http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

---

EDIT: in case the link becomes dead, here's what you can do. Edit "eclipse.ini", and set something like that:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Don't ignore the addendum of MaxPermSize in that post. I couldn't get my project to work until I increased that one.

Comment: Dude, I should have found your answer earlier.. I lost about a day and a half to solve my problem.. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Silvio. In case anyone is on Mac, you can find eclipse.ini in your installation folder i.e. /Applications/eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Remove all errors and warnings from your layouts.
Make sure you are running the eclipse in admin mode (windows users)
Go to your eclipse folder location -> open eclipse.ini file then make sure to match following.

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6-Xms512m-Xmx1024m
```

this may help you a little bit.

and

Change Target SDK in your manifest to 18 for the time being to avoid the crashes. Issue is with android-19. Wait for another update before switching back.

Comment: Yes I too had sdk set to android-19

Comment: This will help if you get the same error on Linux after you've changed all other attributes.