# Android Google Play Service not working on Eclipse 64bit

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm trying to include Google Play Service in my project to use Google Analytics. But just after I include the library in my project I'm unable to build it anymore. There aren't any errors in the project, but Eclipse just stop responding after a while.

From other topics from StackOverflow I've understand that Eclipse does not import libraries correctly with the 64 bit versions.

Is there any thing that I can do to fix this, or I just have to download the 32bit version of ADT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've download the ADT 32bit version and I solved the problem.

I don't know what is the issue over there, but for me this solved my problem, switching to 32 bit version ADT.

Hope it will help some one else too.

Comment: Or if you don't want to change the ADT, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080078/eclipse-crashes-with-a-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error) is another sollution, that worked for me as well.